# Resolved - Magento Custom Module Grid Redirects to 404 - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, database, grid, backend

I'm new to Magento. Have developed a custom module which enables to comment on products on product view page. 
Now I need to create a grid on the backend and display those comments there.
I used [this article](http://markshust.com/2012/07/05/creating-magento-adminhtml-grids-simplified) for the grid part, except that my database table has more fields.

I created files [according to the article for the grid](http://markshust.com/2012/07/05/creating-magento-adminhtml-grids-simplified)

Here is the layout file .....\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\adminproductcomments.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_productcomments_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="cpstest_productcomments/adminhtml_productcomments" name="cpstest_productcomments_productcomments" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_productcomments_index>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please put your adminhtml xml file in proper folder and check it again.

Here is the layout file .....\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\cptest\productcomments\adminproductcomments.xml

seems like your adminhtml file is not being called.

You are new in magento so I suggest you to create module using module creator with same NameSpace and Module Name and then compare it with one you created. That's how you learn from your mistakes as well.

See below link to create module.

http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/

Thanks. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, but I made that change and the error is still there. I will try to fix it by comparing with a working version like you suggested.